# Although I define a channel, nodejs says it's undefined

Tags: discord.js

I'm facing a problem with discord.js. When defining the channel:

```js
client.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
  var role = member.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Member");
  member.addRole(role);
  var channel = member.guild.channels.find("name", "welcome")
  channel.send("Welcome to the server, " + member.name + "!")
});
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of null
    at Client.<anonymous> (E:\Desktop\yeetbot v2.0.1\index.js:42:9)
    at Client.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at Guild._addMember (E:\Desktop\yeetbot v2.0.1\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Guild.js:1298:19)
    at GuildMemberAddHandler.handle (E:\Desktop\yeetbot v2.0.1\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\GuildMemberAdd.js:12:13)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (E:\Desktop\yeetbot v2.0.1\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:105:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (E:\Desktop\yeetbot v2.0.1\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (E:\Desktop\yeetbot v2.0.1\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (E:\Desktop\yeetbot v2.0.1\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (E:\Desktop\yeetbot v2.0.1\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:789:20)
```

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: 1. Stop declaring variable as `var` use `let` if this variable will change in future, or `const` if you want it more immutable.
 2. Best practice isn't "grabbing" discord channel by `name`, but by it's `ID`

Please, tell us more about code logic. Should this bot whisper (DM) to user which has been invited to server or receive a promotion role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var channel = member.guild.channels.find("name", "welcome")
```

It means that .find() function couldn't find the result with the parameters you pass in. Look at if the channel really does exist.

Furthermore, it might be a good idea to do some error handling here.
For example:

```
try{

channel.send('xx','yy,)

}catch(e){

console.log('Error'+e);

}
```

Comment: I guess his function is not `async` cause he uses `var` for define variable, so `try/catch` will fail in his case.

Comment: Make sense, I'll modify the answer when further information is provided.